# Android: how to integrate with another application?

Tags: android

I have a paid android application which uses the google LVL code to authenticate users.

A company would like to pay me so that their application can include a free version of my application.  However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this in a way that won't result in an easily pirated version of my app.  Below are some implementation options I am considering, but none of them seem like particularly good ideas.  Any suggestions?

1. I deliver them an apk which does not use the LVL code.  They could then package my apk with their app, and install it using the ACTION_VIEW intent.  This seems like a bad idea because I think it wouldn't be particularly hard for some rouge user to extract my unsecured apk and distribute it.
2. Maybe I could build a version that checks to see if their app is installed, and if it is it queries their app for some sort of unlock code.  And app will only run if this unlock code succeeds.  My main concern about this is that I have no idea if "querying another app" for an unlock code is accomplishable.

Comment: query a content provider from the other app

Comment: also do a check for their app via the packagemanager to make sure someone isnt spoofing the provider

Comment: I am actually interested in finding out this answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely accomplishable.  As already said one way to query the app is by using a content provider. If you are concerned about security you can introduce additional permission that both apps must hold to access the provider. Although since it doubtfull that both apps have the same signature it won't be as effective.

Another way would be if they had a service that you could bind to and request a code or any other authentication. In this case their service can as well validate your apps validity by querying your apps userId and checking a signature via PackageManager.

Sad news is it's alomost impossible to prevent pirating your app anyway. Even with LVL... Since all this can be decompiled and eventually broken. But at least you can make attackers life harder.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are looking to do I would create a jar out of your project and mark it as a library project. That way you can give your application out to your client but they wont be able to see the actual code you have written. Using this method they will be able to call any method directly which would be easier than having to interact with an apk.

Comment: I've experimented with this, but my app uses resource images/layouts/strings, the references to which must be resolved at compile time.  so, it cannot be packaged as a jar.